# WPF, datagrid cell prefixing

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF, how can I prefix all cells in an editable datagrid column with a dollar sign (`$`), and still bind to a CLR object property of type decimal?

The MSDN documentation tends to point towards styles as ways to customize the visual appearance of elements in a datagrid (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). However, I don't want to set a property. I want to prefix the data with a dollar sign.

I've tried using [data templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#styling_datatemplates). Here's an excerpt from my XAML, showing the data template:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Binding}" x:Key="myDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run>$</Run>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}"></TextBox>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
```

However, the only place I can find to include this in the datagrid is in the `HeaderTemplate` property of `DataGridTextColumn`, as in this excerpt further down in the same XAML. This displays `$` followed by a textbox in the header only. I would like this to happen not in the header, but in all other cells in that row.

```
...
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1"
            Binding="{Binding Path=decimalProperty}"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
...
```

Of course there is code-behind, but the skeletal outline here should describe what I'm trying to do.

Simply changing the property to type string in the code, and prefixing with a dollar sign, is not an option.

Comment: Can you use DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: So you don't want to use `CellStyle` ? Which is designed for what you want

Comment: @Guerudo sorry to mislead, I just can't figure out how to make CellStyle do this. An answer using CellStyle would be great.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian yep that gets it. To help others, would you like to write a quick answer, or should I?

Comment: ...am I reading this wrong? Why wouldn't you just do a currency StringFormat in the binding base for the column?

Comment: @AaronThomas updated as answer.

Comment: @ChrisW umm, you're right. Sorry, I'm a newbie at this, but playing around with it, that would work well also.

Comment: Ok, just so you know, you're going to lose some of your basic tabbing and navigation functionality by doing it the way you have marked as an answer. I'd suggest you look at how [CellEditingTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works, and then in your binding base for the template column for it you'd just do something like `{Binding blah, StringFormat='{}{0:c}'}`

Comment: @ChrisW. true... I actually implemented CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate, and it works better than what I've marked. Would you like to post as an answer, or I could post my own answer... just want to make sure this is good format for SO...

Comment: Oh no worries, points don't get you anything, helping people does. So as long as you have a remedy than it's all good. Cheers amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just seen your edit, just use formatting on the text binding._

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourText, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid manipulating the class just to add some formatting to a property. Yes, the property does use INotifyPropertyChanged, and the class implements ObservableCollection<>, so the C# is fine for data binding from that standpoint.

Comment: Why don't you just use string formatting, which is essentially `<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourText, StringFormat=${0}}" />`. You can obviously do more advanced stuff so that "$" is not visible under certain circumstances...

Comment: Yep, that gets it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn. Refer below code.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header1" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run>$</Run>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding decimalProperty}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

**Code:**

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
        ((DataGridBoundColumn)e.Column).Binding.StringFormat = "c";
}
```

Comment: Nice! For sorting that column, would it provide any benefits to the other solutions mentioned?

Comment: @AaronThomas For this solution sorting works out-of-the-box. But I think it should not be too hard to enable sorting for other solutions. I think you would only need to set https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath.aspx

Comment: @AaronThomas I like this solution because it uses most of the WPF's built-in functionality (to dynamically generate columns based on data source) with just a little tweaking to get the desired result. And it will also work for all future columns/properties which are typeof(decimal), so it is automatically extensible. It uses code-behind, but I think that not all code-behind is bad (as long is it not doing the work of a view-model).